# Fixed Responsive sizes of the soundcloud embed player

Tags: wordpress, css, iframe, soundcloud

Full disclosure, I know just enough css to cause real damage.

I would like the soundcloud embedded player to be large on the desktop and small on mobile. I can't seem to make this work. The fixed size looks amazing on the desktop but too big on mobile:

http://jmobley23.wpengine.com/project/veronica-mars-movie/

the player with a max width and height set to %100 looks great on mobile but too small on the desktop:

http://jmobley23.wpengine.com/project/hateful-8-trailer/

for the love of god man, how do I solve this?

thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please post some of your css or some relevent code to help the community help you

Comment: the only thing I really have are the embed codes. although I did mess around with padding and size of the object container on Wordpress but that was a dead end. Thus, there really is nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some [mobile detection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) classes in the [body tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), your theme `header.php` has to have:

```html
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then add a filter on `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_so_25951935' );

function body_class_so_25951935( $classes ) {
    if( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $classes[] = 'mobile';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'desktop';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Finally, the CSS:

```css
body.mobile .soundcloud-object {
    /* your rules */
}
```

The mobile detection can be fine tuned with something like [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect), as shown in this [blog post](http://themergency.com/add-device-specific-class-names-to-body-tag/).